# Probability of at least three wining lottery tickets in a month with $20$ ticket purchases given probability of a winning ticket is $0.1$

Tags: probability

I am having some trouble understanding what is going on in my statistics course and got stuck on the following problem.

"A woman buys $20$ one-dollar lottery tickets per month. The probability of any ticket being a winning ticket is $0.1$ or $10\%$. Find the probability that at least three of the tickets in a given month are winning tickets is ______. After this, find the average number of winning tickets in any given month."

I do not even know where to begin on the problem and was wondering if someone here could explain the way to calculate this to me.

Answer (score 2):

For the average number of winning tickets you are expected to use the linearity of expectation.  What is the chance that one ticket wins?  The average number of winning tickets is $20$ times this.  *This is a critical concept*

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

> P(at least 3 winning) means:
>   P(winning 3) + P(winning 4) + ...P(winning 20)

P(not winning on a ticket) = 1 - P(winning)
P(losing) = **1 - 0.1 = 0.9**

So, P(winning at least 3) = $$ \Sigma_{r=3}^{20}( ^{20}C_r ) \cdot ({0.1}^r) \cdot ({0.9}^{20-r} )$$
For average no. of winning tickets:
$$ \frac{\Sigma_{k=0}^{20} (^{20}C_k) \cdot ({0.1}^k) \cdot ({0.9}^{20-k})}{20}$$
where k is the number of winning tickets, it can range from **0** to **20**.